# Prisma, increase the connection limit? (Planet Scale)

Tags: prisma, planetscale

```
  Timed out fetching a new connection from the connection pool. More info: http://pris.ly/d/connection-pool (Current connection pool timeout: 10, connection limit: 17)
```

I query the database through prisma and suddenly that error appears. How should I handle it?

On the planet scale, it is stated that up to 250,000 connections are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify the connection limit, you would need to set the `connection_limit` connection string parameter: [Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/connection-pool#setting-the-connection-pool-size).

For example you can set your connection string like this:

```
mysql://tpuf2:*****@ap-south.connect.psdb.cloud/db?sslaccept=strict&connection_limit=100
```

In this case Prisma could have maximum 100 connections with the database.

Comment: Thanks, I use Cloud Run as my web server. It can have up to a thousand instances. If so, is it okay if I set the connection_limit to 100 per instance in order to use all 100000 connections? (100x1000 = 100,000) Or should I just set connect_limit=100000 in this case? Your reply would be very appreciate

Comment: I think you should set connection_limit to 100000 in that case, I assume these instances would be connected with the same connection string so connections would be split among these instances

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because of this https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/connection-management    `You must manually set the connection_limit parameter . For example, if your calculated pool size is 10 and you have 2 instances of your app, the connection_limit parameter should be no more than 5.`